# Context and $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id etc

Tags: typo3

Since Typo3 v10, one should use the context API instead of $GLOBALS['TSFE'].
I read this (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/10.4/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html), but can not understand how to come from here to `GLOBALS['TSFE']->id`...
I simply do not understand how...
Can someone post an example how to get `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all current TYPO3 versions `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id` is still available and the way to go in most cases.

There has been a change in where it's initialized though, so it might be it's not available (anymore) in your case. If that's the case you'll have to add more information about where you want to use it.

Comment: I want to check if the current page id is the root page.
It works with $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id but the extension scanner says I shouldn’t do it…

Comment: I just checked the extension scanner in TYPO3 11. On `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id` I get the message about `Breaking: #93023 - Reworked session handling`. This is a false positive. It looks like it gives that message for all `...->id` lines. If you read the description you'll see it's for `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\AbstractUserAuthentication->id`, not for `TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController->id`. So you can ignore that message in this case.